# Difference in value on page load and page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

So i am trying to read the height and width of img elements created via jquery.

This is the code i am trying to execute

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $.ajax({
            url: 'res/script/getImage.php', 
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                param  : 'Load'
            },
            success: function(result)
            {
                ImageArray = JSON.parse(result);
               for(i=0; i<ImageArray.length; i++)
                {
                        //Read the Image element and update to gallery

                        document.getElementById("gallery").innerHTML += ImageElement;
                        ImageArrayComplete[ImageCounter] = ImageArray[i].image;
                        UserArrayComplete[ImageCounter]  = ImageArray[i].user;

                }

             //Create Canvas
            $('#gallery img').each(function() {
                console.log(this);
                console.log('Width=' + this.width+ 'Height='+this.height);
                createCanvas(this);
            });

            }
        });
});
```

The output of `console.log(this);` is the path for image which is as expected.

But the output of `console.log('Width=' + this.width+ 'Height='+this.height);` is 0 for both width and height during initial page load.

The value then resets to actual width of 200 once page is refreshed.

There is no other error thrown and happens in both firefox and chrome. What am i missing here?

Comment: page  refresh means what ? are your refreshing it by pressing `f5 button`

Comment: @Ravi Yes, i press the f5

Comment: `dataType: 'json'` is missing and what do you get in success function try `console.log(result)`.

Comment: @Jai, is datatype significant? Coz i parse the value once i receive and i have no problem reading other data from result. Output of `console.log(result);` is http://localhost:8080/Gallery/thumb_1234456700.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the ***img*** select has the height and width values?

Comment: If the properties did not exist, they would be "undefined" not "0"

Comment: Yes, else i would not get the values when i refresh the page. The error occurs only during initial page load.

Comment: @de-bugged when you refresh the page, the browser uses a cached copy of the image, which means that it's available instantly, when you set the source. On initial load, without a cached copy, the only place to get the width/height is to hard-code them into the actual html tag: `<img width=200 height=200>`

Comment: Yes, i was suspecting the same.  After hardcoding the width and height, its able to read the width, but height stil fails.  Now the generated image code is `<img src="thumb_1234456700.jpg" height="200" width="200">`  but `console.log('Width=' + image.width+ 'Height='+image.height);` gives output of Width=200 and Height =0;

Comment: Try to use $(this).attr('height') instate of $(this).height().

Comment: @Norguard I'm interested in that hard-code method of the width and height properties, have you some documentation source. The influences at page refresh are my main concerns. thx

Comment: @MichaelKaeser there aren't any official specs which will tell you to do so, however, if you look for articles on async loading of images, you'll see several recommendations of the sort. Much like `canvas`, `img` takes a width and height in HTML which will specify the element's dimensions (in "CSS Pixels" or percent of parent). This sizing is applied before there is any content to go inside, so if you know your image-dimensions (or force them), and want the browser to preallocate that space, without a reflow, then set width and height. `<img width="100" alt="" src="">`

Answer (score 0):

your `ImageElement` object is undefined. try this:

change

```
document.getElementById("gallery").innerHTML += ImageElement;
```

to

```
$('<img/>').attr('src', ImageArray[i].image).appendTo($('#gallery'));
```

and `this` object doesn't have a `height` and `width` attribute. if you wanna get height of it, use :

```
console.log('Width=' + $(this).width() + 'Height=' + $(this).height());
```

Comment: I have defined the ImageElement. It was too long to post. A short version of it would be something as ``ImageElement  = '<img src="'+ImageArray[i].thumb+'">';'`

Comment: Hi Noval, not much difference even after the update. `$(this).height()` , `this.height`, `this.naturalHeight`  all works after refresh of page.  but not at initial page load